# Absence of MainWindow.Xib in iOS 5

Tags: iphone

In iOS 5 sdk with Xcode4.2 i started creating an app with Empty Application Template.But in that template there is no MainWindow.xib.Some posts says to add a MainWindow manually.Is that the right way or proceeed the same without MainWindow.xib for a navigation Based application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty application template does not contain any other files - it's an empty template! If you want to create a navigation based application, you can do it in code by creating a navigation controller and setting it as the root view controller of the application window, or you can create your own xib file and set it to the "Main Interface" in your target summary settings.

Comment: I didn't check the use storyboard option.But no MainWindow is present in the Project.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said you used the empty application template. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!Both works well for me.But the second case works for me when i changed the "Main Interface" to "Main Window" after adding a main window to the project

Answer (score 0):

For information, in XCode4.2/iOS5.0, Apple added the concept of story boards. Now by default, no MainWindow.xib file is created but MainStoryboard.storyboard. You can use it to develop your application. BUT, for backward compatibility, prefer add a nib file that you can name MainWindow.xib. I do not know any other way to use NIB files as it was done before XCode4.2